# Does JTable have a sort event?

Tags: java, swing, sorting, events

I have a program which uses a JTable.
I have given it a RowSorter so that when you click on the column headings the table sorts by that column.

I want to capture the user clicking on the column header and output a debug message.
e.g.

```
System.out.println("You have sorted by first name ascending");
System.out.println("You have sorted by first name descending");
System.out.println("You have sorted by last name ascending");
```

So I need to respond to the sort event.
I have searched for examples online but I can't find any.

Comment: The RowSorter has its own listener interface

Comment: Take a look at [RowSorter#addRowSorterListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/RowSorter.html#addRowSorterListener(javax.swing.event.RowSorterListener))

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it can easily be answered by consulting the JavaDocs and appropriate [tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Comment: I only asked it after consulting JavaDocs, tutorials, searching google and asking my mate.

Comment: Then I don't know what you're consulting.  If you've been able to establish a `RowSorter` for a `JTable`, then you should have been able to narrow the search down.  Even a good IDE would have provided code suggestions to you.  Sorry

Comment: No prob. I have the solution now. Sometimes it is good to post here and be pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, but it is not part of `JTable` but [RowSorter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/RowSorter.html). You can add a `RowSorterListener`:

```
table.getRowSorter().addRowSorterListener(new RowSorterListener() {
    @Override
    public void sorterChanged(RowSorterEvent e) {
        // Sorting changed
    }
});
```